# Is there a way to grant an SFTP user the permission to write to folder without the ability to delete?

Tags: linux, sftp

I am wondering if there is a way to give a user the ability to write to folder without ability to delete from it?

Comment: The ability to delete a file in a directory is controlled by whether or not you have write access to that directory (because you are, effectively, "modifying" the directory). You can create a directory to which a user can write a file but not list files (allow `x` and `w` permissions, do not allow `r`). You can create a directory to which *everyone* can write but people can only delete their *own* files by setting the sticky bit (`/tmp` is usually configured this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly-used SFTP module in the OpenSSH server doesn't break out the SFTP `delete` command from file creation commands like `put`, so you can't block deletion using a config file parameter.

There might be other SFTP server software that offers separate `put` and `delete` permissions.  I haven't checked, so I don't know.

On the other hand, withholding `delete` permission may not be as useful as you believe.  With `delete` denied, a connected client with `put` (write) permission can still overwrite an existing file with an empty file - in effect deleting the file's data.

If you want to prevent the SFTP client from deleting/overwriting files that are important for authentication, such as the SSH authorized_keys file, you can do this.  However, it's done by configuring the SSH server to look for the file in a directory that's not writable by the SFTP account.

Comment: on a side note, access to `authorized_keys` file can be controled by either `chroot` (see link in related tabon the right) or modifying path name in `sshd_config`